# Incorrect answer with too many votes

Tags: discussion

I posted an [answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/5830/1601) that turns out to be incorrect. 
Should I delete it or is leaving it useful as an example of a common mistake?

The answer currently has more votes than the [correct answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/5866/1601), please consider upvoting the [correct one](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/5866/1601).

Comment: If it has educational value, leave it. Emphasize that it is wrong (and the other one is real), and perhaps add what the fallacy in your special approach was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is any harm in leaving it in place, provided there is a suitably prominent indication of this fact. You could, for example, add a quote block at the top of the answer explaining briefly why it is wrong and pointing to @jmbejera's answer. That should catch people's attention.

The time you spent thinking about this can still be useful to the community.